# %sysfunc CATS dropping characters

Tags: sas

Consider the following text value '1/3/2016' from a dataset. This is a badly formatted date value that i cannot correct using `ANYDTDTE.` as I am on SAS 9.0. In this string the day and month are also the wrong way round. This is actually 03JAN2016 in `date9.` format

Therefore I have attempted to correct all of the above with the following macro:

```
%macro date_cats();

        proc sql noprint;
        select scan(matchdate,1,'/'), scan(matchdate,2,'/'), strip(scan(matchdate,3,'/')) into :month, :day, :year
        from test;
        quit;

        %let padder = 0;

        %if %length(&month) < 2 %then
        %let month = %sysfunc(cats(&padder., &month.));
        %put &month.;

        %if %length(&day) < 2 %then
        %let day = %sysfunc(cats(&padder., &day.));
        %put &day.;

        %put %sysfunc(cats(&day., &month., &year.));

        %mend;

        %date_cats();
```

The three `%put` statements produce the following in the log:

```
01
03
132016
```

Can anyone tell me in the final put statement why the final `CATS` statement is either dropping the added '0' character or reverting back to the macro variables being joined before they were padded out?

Thanks

Comment: Why not just use input(bad_date, mmddyy10.)?

Comment: It also looks like you want the functionality of a function which is best done in PROC FCMP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `CATS()` to generate macro variables.

**First** it is totally unneeded since you can concatenate macro variable values by just expanding their values next to each other. Replace

```
%let month = %sysfunc(cats(&padder., &month.));
```

with

```
%let month = &padder.&month.;
```

**Second** when trying to evaluate the arguments to functions like `CATS()` that can take either numeric or character values `%SYSFUNC()` will attempt to evaluate your strings to see if they are numbers. In your case they are numbers so the leading zeros disappear. In other cases you can cause SAS to generate warning messages.

**Third**, if you really want to convert a string like 'M/D/Y' into a string like 'DMY' then assuming the string contains valid dates then just use formats to do the conversion.

```
%let have=1/20/2015 ;
%let want=%sysfunc(inputn(&have,mmddyy10),ddmmyyn8);
```

Answer (score 0):

CATS is seeing numbers and automatically converting them, unhelpfully.

Generally for macro vars you can use the following

```
%put &day.&month.&year.;
```